# How to run an ansible task only once regardless of how many targets there are

Tags: ansible, hipchat

Consider the following Ansible task:

```
- name: stop tomcat
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: pod1
  pre_tasks:
  - include_vars:
      dir: "vars/{{ environment }}"
  vars:
    hipchat_message: "stop tomcat pod1 done."
    hipchat_notify: "yes"
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/stopTomcat8AndClearCache.yml
    - include: tasks/stopHttpd.yml
    - include: tasks/hipchatNotification.yml
```

This stops tomcat on n number of servers. What I want it to do is send a hipchat notification when it's done doing this. However, this code sends a separate hipchat message for each server the task happens on. This floods the hipchat window with redundant messages. Is there a way to make the hipchat task happen once after the stop tomcat/stop httpd tasks have been done on all the targets? I want the task to shut down tomcat on all the servers, then send one hip chat message saying "tomcat stopped on pod 1".

Comment: [`run_once: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) might be your friend here but it is not (from what I recall) usable on an include. I don't think your hipchat yml has so many tasks. You can probably use it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally run the hipchat notification task on only one of the pod1 hosts.

```
- include: tasks/hipChatNotification.yml
  when: inventory_hostname == groups.pod1[0]
```

Alternately you could only run it on localhost if you don't need any of the variables from the previous play.

```
- name: Run notification
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include: tasks/hipchatNotification.yml
```

You also could use the [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) flag on the task itself.

```
- name: Do a thing on the first host in a group.
  debug: 
    msg: "Yay only prints once"
  run_once: true

- name: Run this block only once per host group
  block:
  - name: Do a thing on the first host in a group.
    debug: 
      msg: "Yay only prints once"
  run_once: true
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing it that way as to not bloat up the playbook. I have a very long playbook automating a lengthy deploy process. I suppose I could put a play after a play to notify that the previous play succeeded but that seems too verbose. I don't want to do it the first way - conditionally on one host- because the step isn't considered done until all hosts in the section are complete.

Comment: You probably want to look into the run_once flag inside the included task then. You also might try doing that on a block of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**Ansible handlers** are made for this type of problem where you want to run a task once at the end of an operation even though it may have been triggered multiple times in the play.

You can define a handler section in your playbook and notify it in the tasks, the handlers will not run unless notified by a task, and will only run once regardless of how many times they are notified.

```
handlers:
    - name: hipchat notify
      hipchat:
        room: someroom
        msg: tomcat stopped on pod 1
```

In your play tasks just include a "notify" on the tasks that should trigger the handler and if they change it will run the handler after all tasks have executed.

```
- name: Stop service httpd, if started
  service:
    name: httpd
    state: stopped
  notify: 
    - hipchat notify
```